# Python Regex - remove all duplicate (character and digit)

Tags: python-3.x, regex, duplicates

I am kinda new to Regex and has been trying to build a code to remove duplicates.

The result should look like this 'abcd1"

My code is follow:

```
import re

text = 'aaaaabbbcccddd111'

while re.search(r'([a-z])(.*)\1', text):
    text = re.sub(r'([a-z])(.*)\1', r'\1\2', text)

print(text)
```

However, it will not remove the "1", only the a-z characters.

What should I include to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `re.sub(r'(.)\1*', r'\1', text)`

Comment: Add matching the digits to the character class `([a-z0-9])\1+` and replace with `r'\1'` https://regex101.com/r/sYO49h/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the number group too to the `re.sub()` and avoid the second group:

```
import re

text = 'aaaaabbbcccddd111'
text = re.sub(r'([a-z0-9])(.*)\1', r'\1', text)
#or
text = re.sub(r'([a-z]|[0-9])(.*)\1', r'\1', text)

print(text)
```

gives:

```
'abcd1'
```

---

For strings with multiple group appearance:

```
re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', 'abcddbca123321')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! the code works but not for this text: 'abcddbca123321'